# Use spaces in batch programming with the for /f function

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made a huge batch file with all of these for /f functions. So, the way this works is that the user has to put in the words "Log in". Any other thing, the PC will say "not work". This only works for single word inputs, otherwise, the file will just close. Also, two or more INCORRECT inputs will also close. Here is my code:

```
:main
@echo off
set /p PROGRAM=What do you want to do?
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (password.txt) DO (
set TEXT=%%a
)

if %PROGRAM%==%TEXT% goto works
cls
echo not work
pause
goto main

:works
cls
echo hi
pause
```

The file "password.txt" has the following string "Log in". It is in the same directory of the batch file too!!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: More quotes.  `set "TEXT=%%a"` and `if "%PROGRAM%"=="%TEXT%"`.  Also, remove `@echo off` while debugging.  You're suppressing the very error message that would tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
@echo off
:main
cls
set /p "PROGRAM=What do you want to do ? "
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`Type password.txt`) DO (
    set TEXT=%%a
)

if "%PROGRAM%"=="%TEXT%" goto:works
cls
echo not work
pause
goto:main

:works
cls
echo hi
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!!! This is exactly what I needed and it works!! THANKS A LOT!!!!!

Comment: @ArushAgarampur you forgot to mark it as an answser !